# .htaccess rule to strip script extension and process virtual directories to variables

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am looking for an .htaccess rule for the following situation. I have found fragments of what I am looking for on this site, but I don't have the experience to put them together correctly. The .htaccess rule would process the following scenarios.

The first two examples already work by default with DirectoryIndex, but I included them to make sure they would still work.

```
/
 -> /index.php

/home
 -> /home/index.php

/home/hello
 -> /home/hello.php

/home/hello/there
 -> /home/hello.php?var1=there

/home/hello/there/again
 -> /home/hello.php?var1=there&var2=again
```

Additionally, a trailing / must be optional for each scenario.

Lastly, requests for images or other files should still process correctly. If required, I could put everything that doesn't follow this rule in a folder such as /assets.

So far,

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /$1/$2.php [NC]
```

works for /home/hello -> /home/hello.php

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /$1/$2.php?var1=$3 [NC]
```

works for /home/hello/there -> /home/hello.php?var1=there and

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /$1/$2.php?var1=$3&var2=$4 [NC]
```

works for /home/hello/there/again -> /home/hello.php?var1=there&var2=again

but I have yet to get them to play well together and to also omit a directory for images and other assets.

Thank you very much for any recommendations.

Comment: Do you plan on expanding forever? Like could there be one with a var9 for example? Also please post the rule you have thus far.

Comment: No, it doesn't need to expand forever, though it would be a nice feature for future use or anyone reading. Two variables should satisfy the needs of my application though. Posting existing rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Options       -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond   %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f       [OR]
RewriteCond   %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule   ^                  -                                  [L]

RewriteRule   ^(.*?)/(\w+)/(.*?)/(.*?)/?  $1/$2.php?var1=$3&var2=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule   ^(.*?)/(\w+)/(.*?)/?        $1/$2.php?var1=$3         [L,QSA]

RewriteCond   %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule   ^(.*?)/(\w+)/?              $1/$2.php                 [L]
```

Per Directory evaluation is iterative so you need a stop criteria.  This is what rule 1 does.

The Directory index directive handles the index.php additions.

Rule 2-4 do your SEO to Get mapping.  Note that I've changed parameter 2 to match any word string.

.+? is a non-greedy match.  It will stop at the first /

Comment: Beautifully done and well explained. Thank you so very very much!.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would create different rules myself. In inverse order of what you have listed to  capture. So if you can capture 2 vars do  that first, then try 1 var, then just the page etc.

Here is something that may be of more help http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: Each of the following rules correspond with the last three scenarios in my initial post, but do not "stack" properly as in the first uncommented one seems to always be active and take precedence. `code` RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /$1/$2.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /$1/$2.php?var1=$3 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /$1/$2.php?var1=$3&var2=$4 [NC] `code` will continue to research.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /$1/$2.php?var1=$3&var2=$4 [NC]` should be the first rule in appearance right? it looks last in what you posted here.

Comment: Yes, I eventually was able to combine all the rules with `code`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/? /$1/$2.cfm?var1=$3&var2=$4 [NC]`code` but I like TerrE's solution better. Thanks for your suggestions & comments.